Download Button With Markdown Word format
I have created an R Shiny application to automatically generate a Word report using RMarkdown. It works fine on my local session but not when published on the web. I encounter an error that disconnects the application from the server.
Here is my code:
 #Render report on click 
  report_loc <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$render_report_button,{
    
   #emplacement de sauvegarde
    #output_dir <- file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),  "Bureau", "Informe cata triangular")
    output_dir <- tempfile()
    
    #stockage dans un environnement spécifique 
    
    render_env <- new.env()
    
    render_env$hist_bino <- hist_bino()
    render_env$beta <-beta()
    render_env$p_value <-p_value()
    render_env$binom_test_result <-binom_test_result()
    render_env$n <-n()
    render_env$n1 <-n1()
    render_env$nb <-nb()
    render_env$power <-power()
    render_env$ generate_pie_chart_data <- generate_pie_chart_data()
    
    #Générer le rapport
    
    render(
      input = "sample_markdown_report.Rmd",
      output_dir = output_dir,
      envir = render_env
    )
    
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------    
    
    #update report loc to have rendered file
    report_files <- list.files(output_dir, full.names = TRUE)
    report_loc(report_files)
    print(report_files)  # Add this line to print the report file path in the console
    print(basename(report_files))
  }) 

I tried to properly redefine my variables in the same environment as my RMarkdown report.

Since the code is running on the server now,  it is trying to write to a location on the server, not the client.  Use a shiny downloadHandler instead, unless your goal is actually tor write to a location on the server. In that case, you may need proper write permissions.

Here's how I adapted my code, everything is now working.
UI
 downloadButton("download_report", "Download Report")

SERVER
 # Render report on click
  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "sample_report.docx"  # Set the filename for the downloaded report
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # emplacement de sauvegarde
      output_dir <- tempdir()  # Use tempdir() instead of tempfile() for consistent behavior across sessions
  

  # stockage dans un environnement spécifique 
  render_env <- new.env()
  render_env$hist_bino <- hist_bino()
  render_env$beta <- beta()
  render_env$p_value <- p_value()
  render_env$binom_test_result <- binom_test_result()
  render_env$n <- n()
  render_env$n1 <- n1()
  render_env$nb <- nb()
  render_env$power <- power()
  render_env$generate_pie_chart_data <- generate_pie_chart_data()
  
  # Générer le rapport
  render(
    input = "sample_markdown_report.Rmd",
    output_dir = output_dir,
    envir = render_env
  )
  
  # Get the path of the generated report
  report_file <- file.path(output_dir, "sample_markdown_report.docx")
  
  # Copy the generated report to the download file
  file.copy(report_file, file)
}

)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
